# Ошибка в python multiprocessing: AttributeError, WinError5

Tags: python, веб-программирование, многопоточность, selenium-webdriver

Я пишу одну прогу и по неким причинам не могу раскрыть её код но структуру примерно приведу ниже. В этой проге очень важно быстрота выполнения, а кроме паралельных вычислений, модуль multiprocessing даёт и быстроту тоже, вот я и решил его использовать:

```
#packages
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import 
DesiredCapabilities
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from random import choice

#define one function

#creating if __name__=="__main__" construction
#define and do some no multiprocessing operations with variables

#creating a process
p = Process(target=func, args=(arg0, arg1, arg2))
p.start()
p.join()
```

Я проверял код несколько раз и я уверен что сделал всё правильно, но оно выдаёт ошибку:

```
[ THIS IS STARTING OF CHROMEDRIVER, SO NEVERMIND]
[0121/193818.221:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(967)] Lost UI shared 
context.
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:1780/devtools/browser/8d83f310-e95d- 
4305-9a54-0e9ef95b0621

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[SORRY, BUT SECRET FILENAME].py", line 70, in <module>
    p.start()
  File "C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object '_createenviron. 
<locals>.encodekey'

E:\PyInstaBrut>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 87, in steal_handle
_winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе
```

Я уже спрашивал на английской части форума, там меня просто перенаправили на другой вопрос совершенно не касающийся моего. Прошу пожалуйста помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего дело в самой функции "func" без ее кода сложно сказать. Но в любом случае код запуска процесса надо внести в такую конструкцию:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    p = Process(target=func, args=(arg0, arg1, arg2))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

При запуске нового процесса по сути запускается файл с программой и все что в нем описано запускается снова, таким образом вы вызываете бесконечную рекурсию. Этот код дает понять, что выполнять надо только один раз. Но правда если бы ошибка была только в этом, она должна была быть другой. Попробуйте. Если не поможет возможно есть еще какой то код вне метода, который выполняется?